# Export mysql column to text file and add string

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table column called "title" which has various article names taken from Wikipedia ('Alabama','Alaska' etc etc). I'm using the following code to export the entire column to a text file:

```
SELECT title
FROM mytable order by id
INTO OUTFILE 'C:/wptitles.txt'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

...which works great. The thing is that I need to add "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/" to each of those titles. Is there a way to do that through the above sql? If not, what would be the fastest way to do it?

TIA!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT CONCAT("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/", title)
FROM mytable order by id
INTO OUTFILE 'C:/wptitles.txt'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use [`CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat):

```
SELECT CONCAT('http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/',title)
FROM mytable order by id
INTO OUTFILE 'C:/wptitles.txt'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

Comment: Looks like Megakuh beat you by a few seconds :-). But thanks! I absolutely love SO and it's helpful developers...!